# How can I select a fill in a table?

Tags: r

I am very very new to R. My problem is that I have a database where I want to select 3 columns:

| Flower color | Insect Species who visit the flower | Number of insects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| White | A. mellifera | 3 |
| White | B. terrestris | 1 |
| Yellow | X. violacea | 2 |
| Yellow | A. mellifera | 5 |
| Purple | X. violacea | 10 |

I want to test if these species have a preference for flowers. So I want to build a table which looks like that:

| Flower color | A. mellifera | B. terrestris | X. violacea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| Yellow | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| Purple | 0 | 0 | 10 |

But I don't know how, I tried using "fill" argument in table() function, but it displays 1 table for each "number of insects" data that I have.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `xtabs`

```
> xtabs(NumberOfInsects~.,df)
           InsectSpecieswhoVisitTheFlower
Flowercolor A.mellifera B.terrestris X.violacea
     Purple           0            0         10
     White            3            1          0
     Yellow           5            0          2
```

or `reshape`

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Flowercolor",
  timevar = "InsectSpecieswhoVisitTheFlower"
)
```

which gives

```
  Flowercolor NumberOfInsects.A.mellifera NumberOfInsects.B.terrestris
1       White                           3                            1
3      Yellow                           5                           NA
5      Purple                          NA                           NA
  NumberOfInsects.X.violacea
1                         NA
3                          2
5                         10
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Flowercolor = c("White", "White", "Yellow", "Yellow", 
"Purple"), InsectSpecieswhoVisitTheFlower = c("A.mellifera",
"B.terrestris", "X.violacea", "A.mellifera", "X.violacea"), NumberOfInsects = c(3L,
1L, 2L, 5L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```